# Embedded Timelines

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter

What would be the easiest way to create a dynamic timeline ? What I need is a timeline whose "search" can be updated via javascript.

Twitter has [embedded timelines](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/embedded-timelines), but they need to be created as a widget and then inserted on a page.

I could use some jquery plugin such as [Tweet!](http://tweet.seaofclouds.com/), but it doesn't respect twitter's new [display requirements](https://dev.twitter.com/terms/display-requirements).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not exactly a timeline but...
you can get a JSON object through this url (for example): http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=searchTerm%20secondSearchTerm If you use this you'll be searching for "searchTerm secondSearchTerm", so replace it with a variable in your javascript.

It has some limitations but I hope it helps. More info here: [Twitter Search API](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/using-search).