# Twitter Embedded Multitimelines

Tags: javascript, json, twitter

I trying to embed multi-timelines in my project, but i need a input text where the user types a username from Twitter and with that username i will show his timeline, and for more users, in this post [Embedded Timelines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13099055/embedded-timelines) recommended do it with JSon. How can I do it?. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Twitter has a new [dynamic timeline selection for embedded timelines](https://dev.twitter.com/discussions/18411). With this you can create multiple timelines using only one widget-ID. If you have the [`widget.js`](http://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js) file, the process to embed multi-timelines would be to:

1. User enters a Twitter username into the input text.
2. A JavaScript event creates a new `<a>` tag with the username information (`<a class="twitter-timeline" href="https://twitter.com/[username]" data-widget-id="[id]" data-screen-name="[username]">`)
3. Once the tag is added to the DOM, call `twttr.widgets.load()`

If you want to use JSON to store those usernames, then all you would have to do is save each username in an array, loop over each one, create an `<a>` tag for each one, add all of them to the DOM, then call `twttr.widgets.load()`.

Comment: how would this work dynamically? Like if i had a list of names and wanted my show page to have a different embedded twitter timeline for each user.